# Is it possible to transfer a variable value via NFC?

Tags: android, nfc

My question is, is it possible to send a value of some variable to another device? Let me make it more clear: for example, you have two smartphones with one app opened on both of them. This app has only a "Send" button and an an EditText widget in it. User#1 types something in the EditText, then pushes the "Send" button (these two users are close enough to each other to make NFC work). Then, without receiving any files, the text from first users EditText appears on the second users edit text. Hope I explained it clear enough to understand and my question is not too dull. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Search for "Android Beam". A good start would be [Beaming NDEF Messages to Other Devices](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#p2p)